# facebook app - accessing own page API during development

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

thanks for taking the time to read this!

I am developing an events based application using the facebook graph API. I am up to date with all the recent drama surrounding their changes etc. etc. (thanks, previous Stack Overflow questions!)

In multiple recent places on facebook (blog, changelog, app review etc.) there is this phrase:

"While testing and before submitting for review, your app may only access content that is available on a Page that you own. "

This is what we need to do so we can physically develop our app. Alas, on the graph api explorer armed with our 'app token' I am hit endlessly with:

---

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "CUbrJ1mlpCE"
  }
}
```

---

I'm sure there are others out there managing to develop their apps in order to submit them for review, I've probably overlooked something silly but I've been at this for hours and can't seem to make headway, has anybody else managed to do this?

Comment: Users own pages, not apps. Using your app access token means this request isn’t made by anyone/anything that _could_ be owner of any page to begin with. You need to use your page admin user access token, or a page access token.

Comment: @CBroe, using page access token implies going thru app review process, which is not an option for apps in development stage. I am using page admin access token and experience the same issue. The best way to answer a question is to post a working solution, if you have it of course

Comment: No it doesn’t; any user with a role in the app can be asked for any permission any time; _specifically so_ that you can develep & test your app.